# Why when cloning ThirdPersonController the clones are in not same size and getting a warning?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a script to create GameObjects around the Terrain in random positions but there should be no gameobjects at the same place.

The first problem when i clone ThirdPersonController the size of them is not the same as the one i'm cloning the original.

The original scale is 1,1,1
But when i clone the others the scale is: 1,14,1 and others are 1,17,1 none of them is like the original. And the original is the only one that still fine. 
This is a screenshot of the Scene window when the game is running. In the Inspector on the right you can see the Scale the value of Y it's 22.

If i will change the value to 1 it will be fine but why they are all created with different Y values ? Same problem if i create other GameObjects.

This is a screenshot of the GameObject i attached the script to:

[image: Script in inspector]

And this is a screenshot while the game is running and how the cloned objects looks like. In this case the Y value of this clone is 28:

[image: Cloned object]

And the script:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class CloneObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ObjectToCreate;
    public int objectsHeight = 3;
    [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject[] objects;

    // for tracking properties change
    private Vector3 _extents;
    private int _objectCount;
    private float _objectSize;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How far to place spheres randomly.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 Extents;

    /// <summary>
    ///     How many spheres wanted.
    /// </summary>
    public int ObjectCount;
    public float ObjectSize;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        Clone();
        objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ClonedObject");
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // prevent wrong values to be entered
        Extents = new Vector3(Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.x), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.y), Mathf.Max(0.0f, Extents.z));
        ObjectCount = Mathf.Max(0, ObjectCount);
        ObjectSize = Mathf.Max(0.0f, ObjectSize);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        Extents = new Vector3(250.0f, 20.0f, 250.0f);
        ObjectCount = 100;
        ObjectSize = 20.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void Clone()
    {
        if (Extents == _extents && ObjectCount == _objectCount && Mathf.Approximately(ObjectSize, _objectSize))
            return;

        // cleanup
        var ObjectsToDestroy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ClonedObject");
        foreach (var t in ObjectsToDestroy)
        {
            if (Application.isEditor)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(t);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(t);
            }
        }

        var withTag = GameObject.FindWithTag("Terrain");
        if (withTag == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Terrain not found");

        for (var i = 0; i < ObjectCount; i++)
        {
            var o = Instantiate(ObjectToCreate);
            o.tag = "ClonedObject";
            o.transform.SetParent(base.gameObject.transform);
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ObjectSize, Random.Range(3, 50)/*ObjectSize*/, ObjectSize);

            // get random position
            var x = Random.Range(-Extents.x, Extents.x);
            var y = Extents.y; // sphere altitude relative to terrain below
            var z = Random.Range(-Extents.z, Extents.z);

            // now send a ray down terrain to adjust Y according terrain below
            var height = 10000.0f; // should be higher than highest terrain altitude
            var origin = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            var ray = new Ray(origin, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;
            var maxDistance = 20000.0f;
            var nameToLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Terrain");
            var layerMask = 1 << nameToLayer;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
            {
                var distance = hit.distance;
                y = height - distance + y; // adjust
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
            }

            // place !
            o.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y + objectsHeight, z);
        }
        _extents = Extents;
        _objectCount = ObjectCount;
        _objectSize = ObjectSize;
    }
}
```

What i want to do is to be able to clone any gameobject and the clones should be the same size like the original everything the same.

Another problem is i wanted to gather all characters under a GameObject so i added a empty gameobject named it: Characters.
When i drag the ThirdPersonController to be child of Characters the cloned objects are out of the terrain and falling down.

And last, i'm still getting a warning not sure if this what make the problem but i can't figure out why i'm getting the warning and how to solve/fix it:

> Terrain not hit, using default height !
>     UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
>     cs:109)
>     cs:34)

Line 109 is:

```
Debug.LogWarning("Terrain not hit, using default height !");
```

And line 34:

```
Clone();
```

Comment: I managed to solve the size problem. I changed before this line with a Random.Range for the Y size. o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ObjectSize, Random.Range(3, 50)/*ObjectSize*/, ObjectSize); and it should be: o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ObjectSize, ObjectSize, ObjectSize); I forgot i changed this line. Now i need to solve the two other problems. The warning message and the problem when moving the ThirdPersonController as child under Characters.